# iperf3: unable to create a new stream

Tags: sockets, tcp, stream, udp, iperf3

I have 2 users on a system. One user is able to provide all the logs for iperf3 installed on the system. But second user gives error as:

> iperf3: error - unable to create a new stream: No such file or
>   directory

Does iperf3 requires some specific file/directory write access? Or tcp/udp socket write access? or some other access?

Edit:
Is it possible to force iperf3 to create temp files on a specific location and not default location?

Any lead would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

I wish we knew the version of iperf3 and what operating system this was.

Anyway.  By default, iperf3 creates a temporary, memory-mapped file, in one of the following directories (tried in order until one succeeds):

1. The value of the ${TMPDIR} environment variable
2. The value of the ${TEMP} environment variable
3. The value of the ${TMP} environment variable
4. /tmp

It sounds like the user who got the error isn't able to create a file in any of those places.  Perhaps those environment variables are set to values that don't make sense?  I'd suggest setting ${TMPDIR} to some location that the user can write to.

Bruce.

Answer (score 0):

I've checked my security rights for temp and iperf3 foldres, also I set up my user as an owner of these folders (but I was in group "administrators", starter owner of them). Also I logged out from system and logged in. After that iperf began to work normally.

Answer (score 0):

if you use iperf3.exe in windows taskplaner with a user without administrator rights you get the same error message. if you execute iperf3 direct on cmd or powershell it will works without administrator rights.

Workaround:

Don't use user ressources. Run the windows task with account: "NT-AUTORITÄT\System" or "NT-AUTHORITY\System" and highest privileges. Notice that your batch, powershell script and iperf3.exe is stored on your local pc not in your network.

Now will the script execute by taskplaner with administrator rights and the computer ressources.